# SCons: How to call a self defined python function in scons script and make right dependency

Tags: python, scons

I write a python function such as replace strings and called in scons script.

```
def Replace(env, filename, old, new):
    with open(filename,"r+") as f:
    d = f.read()
    d = d.replace(old, new)
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(d)
    f.close()
env.AddMethod(Replace,'Replace')
```

In SConscript

```
lib = env.SharedLibrary('lib', object, extra_libs)
tmp = env.Command([],[],[env.Replace(somefile, 'A', 'b')] )
env.Depends(tmp,lib )
```

What i expect is to run the Replace() method after the lib built.
but scons always run the Replace() in the first round script parsing phrase.
it seems i am missing some dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you're probably looking for [builders that execute python functions](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/x3610.html).

The tricky bit is that SCons doesn't really want to work the way you're forcing it to. Build actions should be repeatable and non-destructive, in your code you're actually destroying the original contents of `somefile`. Instead, you can use the target/source paradigm and some kind of template file to achieve the same result.

```
import os
import re

def replace_action(target, source, env):
    # NB. this is a pretty sloppy way to write a builder, but
    #     for things that are used internally or infrequently
    #     it should be more than sufficient
    assert( len(target) == 1 )
    assert( len(source) == 1 )
    srcf = str(source[0])
    dstf = str(target[0])
    with open(srcf, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        # In cases where this builder fails, check to make sure you
        # have correctly added REPLST to your environment
        for old, new in env['REPLST']:
            contents = re.sub( old, new, contents )
        with open( dstf, "w") as outf:
            outf.write(contents)

replace_builder = Builder(action = replace_action)

env = Environment( ENV = os.environ )
env.Append( BUILDERS = {'Replace' : replace_builder } )
b = env.Replace( 'somefile', ['somefile.tmpl'], REPLST=[('A','b')] )
lib = env.SharedLibrary('lib', object + [b], extra_libs )
```

Note that in my testing, the replace function wasn't playing nicely with multi-line data, so I've just swapped to using full regular expressions (`re.sub`). This is probably slower, but offers significantly more flexibility.